# Error trying to use writeFile with NodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, writefile

I am trying to write a function using fs.writeFile but I am getting this error.

```
TypeError [ERR_INVALID_CALLBACK]: Callback must be a function. Received undefined
```

I am not so familiar with JS so I'd appreciate the help.

My function:

```
write(fileName, cb) {
fs.writeFile(fileName, function(succ, err) {
  if (err) {
    cb(err);
  } else {
    cb(succ);
  }
});
```

}

And this function is being called by this:

```
// write string version to file, starting at root element
root.write('test.svg', () => console.log('done writing!'));
```

This last code is correct (it was a test provided by the instructor).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `fs` module `writeFile`, from the [fs callback api](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#callback-api), takes in three parameters. First being the name of the file, the second is the data to write, and third is a callback for when the write is finished:

```
fs.writeFile('message.txt', data, (err) => {
  if (err) throw err;
  console.log('The file has been saved!');
});
```

Since you are only passing in two parameters the callback is undefined, as the error states.

also, the callback does not take in two parameters

[read more about `fs.writeFile`](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fswritefilefile-data-options-callback)

Comment: thanks for the reply! i tried this before, and even so i get an error because data isn't defined. data would be the info from inside the file, right?

Comment: data is what you are writing to the file. are you wanting to read the file?

Comment: ohhh thank you so much! i didn't realize the data would be what is going to be added to the file. thanks!!